# Is there a preferred function for generating a private/public key-pair for an elliptic curve?

Tags: go, cryptography, elliptic-curve, key-generator

Is one of the following two functions preferred over the other?
Do they both do the same thing, just with a different implementation?

- [crypto/ecdsa/#GenerateKey](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/ecdsa/#GenerateKey)
- [crypto/elliptic/#GenerateKey](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/elliptic/#GenerateKey)

Both seem to return the same values, just in a different package.

I want to create a private/public key-pair for the following curve

- [brainpoolP512r1](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/keybase/go-crypto@v0.0.0-20200123153347-de78d2cb44f4/brainpool#P512r1)

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In elliptic curve cryptography the private key is simply a large random number in some range, usually `0 - 2^256`, the range is defined by curve itself though, usually the order of some cyclic subgroup, or the entire curve order when dealing with prime order curves.

ECC is used for many things, Elliptic Curve Diffie Hellman, Elliptic Curve Signature (ECDSA) they all require scalar **multiplication** of a given private key by the curve's generator point **to establish the public key**.

These scalar multiplication functions are implemented differently for various security and efficiency reasons.

In short are three types of multiplication function:

- Fixed-base
- Variable-base
- Double-base

ECDSA uses fixed-base, ECDH uses variable-base.

There is intuition here, during ECDH you must multiply your private key by someone else's "*variable*" public point.

Anyway, to use Brainpool, you must generate a key suitable for that curves order, and multiply it by the curves generator point. Usually most API's allow specification of the curve.

By the way, don't use Brainpool, it [sucks](https://safecurves.cr.yp.to).

Comment: So @rico, do you want to use the key for signing? if so use ECDSA.generateKey and pass Bp512 as the curve

Comment: Also the private key is not the generator.

Comment: I accidentally pressed enter while changing the sentence... So here is the actual comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed comment! I think I understand most of what you wrote, but I don't have a clue why one would choose a specific multiplication algorithm over another... Since I'm just doing DH I guess I'll use the `elliptic` implementation. Could you explain why I'd choose one implementation over the other? Also, I switched the curve to Ed448. PS: I think the private key is the scalar multiplier for the generator point that is used for deriving the public key with group operations.

Comment: This is how I'm generating keys and deriving shared data: https://pastebin.com/ANVSTQ7r

Comment: Will take a look at this in a little bit and give you feedback.

Comment: @Rico you can't use ECDSA with ed448, ECDSA and EdDSA are both digital signature altos, but not compatible. You want this: https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/ed25519/

Comment: I thought both functions just derive a key-pair from the generator using a random (but in the field) scalar. Point doubling and addition works different on an Edwards curve compared to an elliptic curve but I thought that'd just change the implementation for the functions for the `Curve` interface https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/elliptic#Curve. I don't want to sign anything for now, I just used the `ecdsa` implementation because I liked using the `PrivateKey` struct... I think I got things mixed up, I'm not doing Ed448 but using it's curve `Curve448` for doing DH. https://pastebin.com/Xkn99BLa

Comment: I thought the curve was called Ed448, because of this (https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/625.pdf) title `Ed448-Goldilocks, a new elliptic curve`, but the Wikipedia article clarified it for me (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EdDSA#Ed448).

Comment: So different curves have different generators you use to scalar multiply. Also some keys are clamped before use (made a multiple of 8 to avoid small subgroup attacks). If you want to do just ECDH use curve25519 (https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/crypto/curve25519) - let me know if you need more help, if answered pls mark question as answered